# How to definitely use column names in Google Sheet Query

Tags: google-sheets

`query` function doesn't let you use column names; you have instead to use letters if you refer to a cell range or `ColN` if you refer to an array.
This is very annoying, most of all when you alter the queried table adding, deleting or exchanging columns.

I would like to use column names, like in a standard SQL query.

Comment: This question answered my question: when using QUERY over an array, in the SELECT, the column names are not letters, but rather Col1, Col2, Col3…. Incredibly hard to find this! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get around this by splitting the Query formula and using other formula's to automatically get the desired column names from a list.

For example if you have a table in range `A1:E15` with headers "H1, H2, H3, H4, H5", and you'd like to only get columns H3 & H5:

1. Store the desired headers (H3 & H5) in another table/range as a list - lets say this range is `G1:G2`
2. Use `MATCH` formula along with `TextJoin` formula to generate an concatenated string like `Col3, Col5`

   ```
   =TextJoin(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IFERROR("Col"&MATCH(G1:G6,$A$1:$E$1,0),"")))
   ```

   - Lets say this was in cell `H1`
3. You can refer to this cell in your `Query` formula like below

   ```
   =QUERY({A1:E20},"SELECT "&H1&" WHERE Col2='w'")
   ```

You can see it in action in below screenshot:
[image: Sample Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be recurring to some custom function created by a script, but when you have a not so small table you surely will incur in some error due to the exceeding computation time.

The most efficient solution (using only native functions) I found is as follows.

Suppose you are working on a sheet range, your column names are in row 1 and you want to refer to the column "salary"; you can obtain the column letter by

```
substitute(address(1,match("salary",A1:1,0),4),"1","")
```

Instead, if you are querying arrays, it is simpler; the string you need is

```
"Col"&match("salary",A1:1,0)
```

The final query could be not so elegant, but the efficiency is guaranteed:

```
query(
  employeessheet!A:E,
  "select "&substitute(address(1,match("salary",employeessheet!A1:1,0),4),"1","")&" where ...",
  1)
```